# MessageBox prevents exiting from application

Tags: windows, modal-dialog, exit, messagebox

Our application loads 3rd party DLLs that sometimes pops MessageBoxes.
We've notices that sometimes we can't just use exit(0) when there's an open MessageBox.

How can we still force an exist in such a case?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, Windows Vista and beyond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use brute force you may call the `TerminateProcess()` function. I'm not sure this is a good idea, you may want to detect if there's an open message box and send a close to it (for example using a `FindWindow()`)

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Does it hangs because the MessageBox is modal? I found the handle of the specific window and it won't close with CloseWindow(), am I missing something here?

Comment: You may try to send him a [ESC] keypress.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your ugly DLL calls `MessageBox` (or whatever) from within `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` or `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`.

If this happens in the same thread (i.e. the thread the calls `exit`) you may try to call `PostQuitMessage` right **before** the application exit. This should abort any message loop. If this happens in another thread - you may call `PostThreadMessage`.

There's also an option to intercept calls to Win32 API functions by hooking the appropriate module (Exe/Dll) import table. Invented by J.Richter (if I remember correctly). http://www.player.idv.tw/prog/index.php/APIHook